# how to print output and errors to separate files in batch script

Tags: batch-file

### Executor_Scrubbing.bat

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=" %%G IN (SchemaList.txt) DO (call SQL_Execute.bat %%G %%H %%I %%J)
```

### SQL_Execute.bat

```
SET "usr=%1"
SET "pwd=%2"
SET "COMP_ID=%3"
SET "dbsvr=%4"

mkdir %usr%_%dbsvr%
sqlplus -S %usr%/%pwd%@%dbsvr% @.\query.sql %3 >.\%usr%_%dbsvr%\log.txt 2>.\%usr%_%dbsvr%\Errors.txt
```

Executor_Scrubbing.bat calls SQL_Execute.bat and sql script mention in SQL_Execute.bat gets executed on schema listed in text file

The problem is `">.\%usr%_%dbsvr%\log.txt 2>.\%usr%_%dbsvr%\Errors.txt"`. Redirecting output and errors to separate files. It dosen't print errors in 2nd file, Errors.txt, but logs appear in log.txt correctly

Answer (score 0):

If SQLPLUS is like SQLCMD you will find that it only get output to STDERR (2>) if the launch of the SQLPLUS command fails. SQL errors go to STDOUT. You may need to send STDOUT to a temp file, parse that, and output to desired place as needed.

Comment: Sqlplus commands executes sql script in that sql script if some sql statements fails or generate errors then that errors should be redirected to separate file